# how to push variation to a property href

Tags: javascript, html

```
var href_ = 'www.google.com';
$(this).append("<a href=`href_`>google gogo</a>")
```

this code doesn't work, my purpose is to put character type to href property how to put var to a tag's href?

My real purpose is as seeing below code to move to where my girlfriend picture.

I want implement code that if I click a tag link then moving to picture href.

href for example

girlfriend0.jpg
girlfriend1.jpg
etc...
girlfriend99.jpg;

```
var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
var href_ = './../img/girlfriend'+ranNum+'.jpg';
```

How do I change my code?

Comment: What is `$(this).append("<a href=`href_`>google gogo</a>")` inside of?

Comment: You mean $(this).append(\`<a href="${href_}">google gogo</a>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together what I thought you were looking for. All you need to do is:

1. Change the references in the `images` to your pictures
2. Update the `url`
3. Change `document.body` to `this`

```js
var images = [
   'DeJ2ifS2V2zlu/giphy.gif',
   'GpyS1lJXJYupG/giphy.gif',
   'fGuqeA6PiXINa/giphy.gif'
  ];
  
var url = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/',
    picture = images[Math.ceil(Math.random() * images.length - 1)],
    link = url + picture;

$(document.body).append('<a href='+ link + '>Click here</a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for teaching me + link + 스킬 but var url = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\3단원 복습\img\girlfriend1.jpg';
           var picture =['girlfriend1.jpg' ,'girlfriend2.jpg' ,'girlfriend3.jpg','girlfriend4.jpg','girlfriend5.jpg'];
           var link =url+'\'+picture[ranNum] ;  this code doesn`t work and  i don`t know why?